# Extracting only certain lines from a file

Tags: shell, unix, bioinformatics

I was wondering if can help me with this:

I have two text files.. each file contains a list of marker ID's. For sake of simplicity: File 'A' has 1000 ID's and information for each ID in a single line(row). File 'B' only has a list of about 200 ID's. 
Is there a way I can given file 'B' as input and extract data from file 'A' for only those ID's that are present in file B?

File A:

```
rs149201999     16050408        T       C
rs146752890     16050612        C       G
rs139377059     16050678        C       T
rs188945759     16050984        C       G
```

File B:

```
rs2508081
rs12157537
rs2334336
rs11703370
```

Comment: File A but only with the IDs present in file B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making some assumptions about your files

```
awk 'NR==FNR {id[$1]=1; next} $1 in id' fileB fileA
```

I assume that the id is the only thing in fileB, and that the id is the first field of fileA

Alternately, `join <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB)`

Comment: Yes. ID is the only field in file B and the first field (out of 4 fields) in file A

Comment: @glenn jackman Can you please explain what you did in your first answer? How did you use awk to compare between both the files?

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the Unix join tool.

Comment: This is not a good answer by Stack Overflow standards. You should expand your answer by explaining how to use `join` to solve this problem.